# integrating myspace sdk for iphone tutorial

Tags: iphone, myspace

i need a tutorial or guide for using myspace sdk in iphone application.

i have downloaded myspace sdk for iphone but can't use myspace

sdk in my iphone application, because there are a lot of stuffs to do in

importing  the sdk in iphone application. If there is any tutorial or guide

please share with US.

Thanks

Comment: one very quick question did you try to run the example/demo project that you downloaded with sdk ? And did that run successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw that this question is old "Mar 7 11" but for those who still face this problem;
Here is the guidance for them.

1) Read and implement the following starting guideline from the myspace documentation.
http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Example_Application:_Hello_World

By following this guideline you will be able to setup the app setup at myspace like you do for facebook or twitter.

2) Once you will be done with it, you can verify the auth and other services from the api tool:
http://developer.myspace.com/community/myspace/testandtinker.aspx

3) Download the Ios sdk with a demo project from the following link:
http://code.google.com/p/myspace-iphone-sdk/

4) Once you will be able to run the demo/example ios demo.Try to see the file in "MySpaceSDKServices.plist" in the demo sdk project and edit it accordingly the files settings done at the myspace app creation panel.

Hope it will be beneficial for someone fighting with it :).

Comment: can some one provide me with the link where demo example is availble. I googled a lot but couldnt find that

Comment: did u tried the above mentioned links ? http://code.google.com/p/myspace-iphone-sdk/source/checkout === i guess not.

Comment: (facepalm) if you are on MAC open terminal type svn co code.google.com/p/myspace-iphone-sdk/source/checkout it will download the source code in the respective directory

Comment: If your mac version > 10.8 then read the article http://blog.grapii.com/2012/08/svn-missing-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/ to enable SVN and once its enable you can download the code from the following command svn checkout http://myspace-iphone-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ myspace-iphone-sdk-read-only    else if your mac version < 10.8.0 it should work for too...

Comment: SVN was already enabled...but problem was with url. had to include http:// also in the url. Thanks for the help